# Wildcards in a Search and Replace Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, wildcard, pickle

I am fairly new to Python so if my terminology is wrong I apologize. I am running Python 2.6.5, I am not sure about updating to 3.0 since Python was initially downloaded with my spatial analysis software.
I am writing a program to search and replace column headers in multiple comma delimited text files.  Since there are over a hundred headers and they are the same in all the files I decided to create a dictionary and 'pickle' to save all the replacements (got the idea from reading other posts).  My issue comes in when I noticed there are tabs and spaces within the text file column headings, for example:

```
    ..."Prev Roll #: ","Prev Prime/Sub","Frontage : ","Depth            : ","Area             : ","Unit of Measure  : ",...
```

So I thought why not just stick in a wildcard at the end of my key term so the search will match it no matter how many spaces are dividing the name and the colon.  I was trying the * wildcard, but it doesn't work, when I run it no matches/replacements are made. Am I using the wildcard correctly? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Or should I do away with the dictionary pickle?
Below is a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
import cPickle as pickle

general_D = { ....
             "Prev Prime/Sub" : "PrvPrimeSub",
             "Frontage*" : "Frontage",
             "Depth*" : "Depth",
             "Area*" : "Area",
             "Unit of Measure*" : "UnitMeasure",
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to parse and write your comma-separated data.
2. Use the string [strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method to remove unwanted spaces and tabs.
3. Do not include `*` in your dict key names. They will not glob as you
   hope. They just represent literal `*`s there.
4. It is probably better to use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) instead of pickle. JSON is
   human-readable, independent of programming language. Pickle may have
   problems even across different versions of Python.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying your answers out! Lots of learning to do!